# Assets compilation Ckeditor rails in heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, assets

I am having troubles using Ckeditor in production environment.

I have 2 environments, staging and production, both of them are in Heroku.

I am able to see Ckeditor in staging environment but not prod.

My configuration is the following:
config/environments/production.rb:

```
# Precompile additional assets
config.assets.precompile += Ckeditor.assets
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js )
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
```

config/initializers/assets.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/* )
```

app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require ckeditor/init
```

(Which basically following https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor documentation)

Both environment staging and production use RAILS_ENV=production.

I use Amazon S3 to serve my assets, which fine, because i can see that the javascript functionnalities, icons and images are present in production.

Is there anything obvious that i am missing here ?

Thanks!

P.S: I am using RoR 4.2 and ckeditor 4.1.1

EDIT:

1 - I verified the javascript served in both environment, and the file is the same ! and Ckeditor javascript code is present in both. So the issue is not asset precompilation but something else...

2 - The ckeditor.js file is present in the bucket but i'm still getting 404 not found response from server. The file is under assets/ckeditor/ckeditor-xxxx.js

Comment: You said the javascripts files are served in Prod. So, are you getting JS errors? I had the exact same issue, but it had to do with Asset compilation.

Comment: Yes after investigation it seems that the file public/assets/ckeditor/ckeditor-xxxx.js is not found in the assets. I' m not sure how should i include it, since prod and staging have exactly the same configuration ( except for S3 buckets )

Comment: You can try to precompile the asset to see if it's going to fix it. RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:precompile I know it's not a fix, but I actually ended up doing that for one of my projects.

Comment: @Yosep: I could fix it finally! Check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i could fix this issue by adding the gem

```
gem 'non-stupid-digest-assets', '~> 1.0.4'
```

It compiles the asset without the digest.

The problem was that ckeditor assets were compiled with the digest, but in the code ( inside the gem ), it was referenced directly without digests.

Hope it will help whoever encouter this problem...